# computing null space via opencv

Tags: matlab, opencv, linear-algebra, basis

Is there an alternative command in OpenCV to `null` command in MATLAB, which given a vector `v` computes an orthogonal basis for the null space which `v` is one of its basis vectors?

Comment: `null` takes a matrix, not a vector.  (There's no such thing as the null-space of a vector.)

Comment: In matlab it can take a vector!

Comment: did you check `edit null.m`? computed using a simple SVD operation..

Comment: I stand corrected.